# Infinite Scrolling in Masonry

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I don't know JavaScript but I would really like this for my website.
Here is the JavaScript I use for masonry.  Can somebody show me how to get infinite scrolling working?  I've googled it with no luck.

```
<script>
    (function($){ 

//Finding min and max values in array from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/769
Array.prototype.min = function(){ return Math.min.apply({},this) };
Array.prototype.max = function(){ return Math.max.apply({},this) };

$.fn.masonry = function() {
    this.each(function() {

        var wall = $(this);

        if ( wall.children().length > 0 ) { // check if the element has anything in it

            if( wall.children('.masonryWrap').length == 0 ) {      // checks if the masonryWrap div is already there
                wall.wrapInner('<div class=\"masonryWrap\"></div>');
            }
            var mWrap = wall.children('.masonryWrap');

            var brick = mWrap.children();
            var brickW = brick.outerWidth(true);
            var colCount = Math.floor( mWrap.width() / brickW ) ;

            var colH=new Array();
            for ( i=0; i < colCount; i++) {
                colH[ i ] =  0 ;
            }       

            mWrap.css({ position: 'relative' });

            brick.css({
                    float: 'none',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    display: 'block'
                })
                .each(function(){
                    for ( i=colCount-1; i > -1; i-- ) {
                        if ( colH[ i ] == colH.min() ) {
                            var thisCol = i;
                        }
                    }
                    $(this).css({
                        top: colH[ thisCol ],
                        left: brickW * thisCol
                    });
                    colH[ thisCol ] += $(this).outerHeight(true);
                });

            mWrap.height( colH.max() );
        }

        return this; 
    });
};
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: Can you possibly set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Either use one of these themes http://zen-themes.tumblr.com/ which has infinite scroll and masonry built in already, or search more. Trust me, I've had this issue before and there are TONS of posts regarding masonry and infinite scroll already.